# fluid layout footer with same height separators

Tags: html, css, fluid-layout

I am developing the footer of a fluid layout web page. Here is the html:

```
<div id="footer">
    <div id="lists">
        <div class="list1" id="list-sep">
            <p id="footer-par">
                Lorem Ipsum<br />
                Lorem Ipsum<br />
                Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum<br />
                Lorem Ipsum<br />
                Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum<br />
                PEC<br />
                Lorem Ipsum<br />
                <br />
                &copy; region<br />
            <p>
        </div>
        <div class="list1" id="list-sep">
            <ul>
                <li class="footer-point">President</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsu</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="list1" id="list-sep">
            <ul>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="list1">
            <ul>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum </li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <hr />
</div>
```

And here is the CSS:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#footer {


    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-top:40px;


}

#lists {

    width:75%;

    height:auto;
    margin:20px auto 0 auto;



}



.list1 {


    float:left;
    width:20%;
    height:100%;
    min-height:116px;
    display:block;
    padding-left:4%;
    /*padding-bottom:44px;*/
    /*padding-top:21px;*/


}


#list-sep {

    border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC;


}

.footer-point {

    display:block;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-family:'Myriad Pro';
    font-size:0.6em;
    color:#CCC;
}

#footer-par {

    margin-top:20%;
    margin-bottom:20%;
    font-family:'Myriad Pro';
    font-size:0.6em;
    color:#CCC;

    height:100%;

}

ul {


    margin-top:20%; 
    margin-bottom:20%;

}
```

The columns height and width must adapt to the amount of text inside them (when resizing the browser window), but the three separators must have the same height. Moreover, when resizing the browser I want that the three separators adapt their height based on the amount of text, but they must have the same height. In other words the separators must adapt to the column with most text. Anyone can help me? Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Check out http://jsliang.com/eqHeight.coffee/

Comment: Sadly, you can only achieve that by using <table> or JS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS `display: table` is what you want here. E.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
@charset "UTF-8";
/* CSS Document */

* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#footer {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    margin-top:40px;
}

#lists {
    display: table;
    width:75%;
    height:auto;
    margin:20px auto 0 auto;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.list1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width:20%;
    padding:4%;
}


#list-sep {
    border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC;
}

.footer-point {
    display:block;
    margin-top:5px;
    font-family:'Myriad Pro';
    font-size:0.6em;
    color:#CCC;
}

#footer-par {
    margin-top:20%;
    margin-bottom:20%;
    font-family:'Myriad Pro';
    font-size:0.6em;
    color:#CCC;
    height:100%;
}

ul {
    margin-top:20%; 
    margin-bottom:20%;
}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<div id="footer">
    <div id="lists">
        <div class="list1" id="list-sep">
            <p id="footer-par">
                Lorem Ipsum<br />
                Lorem Ipsum<br />
                Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum<br />
                Lorem Ipsum<br />
                Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum<br />
                PEC<br />
                Lorem Ipsum<br />
                <br />
                &copy; region<br />
            <p>
        </div>
        <div class="list1" id="list-sep">
            <ul>
                <li class="footer-point">President</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsu</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="list1" id="list-sep">
            <ul>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="list1">
            <ul>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum</li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum </li>
                <li class="footer-point">Lorem Ipsum </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```